# Lag/Animation issues on newer android versions (Marshmallow and up)

Tags: android, performance, animation

I've made an app with various custom views and multiple fragments; the problem is that animations/translations are perfect on android lollipop, but on marshmallow and nougat there is lag/delay when clicking on buttons and opening pages and the animations are a bit slow as well.

I'm not sure what the problem is and how this can be solved; if required, here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})



compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'

compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.wefika:flowlayout:0.4.1'
compile 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-library:1.5.8@aar'
compile 'com.github.stfalcon:chatkit:0.2.2'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Edit**: 
One thing I forgot to mention: the lag is apparent on the first actions mostly. For example, on the first press of the chat button, chat fragment is loaded and there is a delay and the animation is not perfect for the button; on the first card swipe to the right, there is a slight stutter; on the first vertical swipe after the horizontal card swipe, the vertical viewpager animation snaps into place etc.

Comment: phone or emulator?

Comment: same problem on both

Comment: Just out of curiosity, when you're performing the animations, are you setting a delay on the animation?
In some cases, the default animation delay can be different for Lollipop. I would make sure that the default delay during your animation transitions are not different across these versions.

Comment: When replacing the fragment, I call .setTransition(FragmentTransition.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
All values are default